# Не хватает оперативной памяти для открытия файла

Tags: php, file-get-contents, glob

Есть код

```php
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

function listFile($name)
{
    $list = glob($name . '.*');
    foreach($list as $filename)
    {
        echo('<div>' . $filename . '</dev><br/>');
        #echo('<dev><pre>' . file_get_contents($filename) . '</pre></dev><br/>');
        echo('<br/>');
    }
    unset($list);

    $list = glob($name);
    foreach($list as $path)
    {
        listFile($path . '/*');
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Menu</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php listFile('*'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Но не хватает 8 GB memory для открытия данных в файлах.
Файлов много
Вот список:

```
etc/ca-certificates.conf
etc/conf.d
etc/init.d
etc/logrotate.d
etc/modprobe.d
etc/modules-load.d
etc/profile.d
etc/resolv.conf
etc/sysctl.conf
etc/sysctl.d
etc/udhcpd.conf
etc/apk/protected_paths.d
etc../Playground/-devel@lists.alpinelinux.org-4a6a0840.rsa.pub
etc../Playground/-devel@lists.alpinelinux.org-5243ef4b.rsa.pub
etc../Playground/-devel@lists.alpinelinux.org-5261cecb.rsa.pub
etc../Playground/-certificates.list
etc/ca-certificates/update.d
etc/modprobe.d/aliases.conf
etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
etc/modprobe.d/i386.conf
etc/modprobe.d/kms.conf
etc/network/if-down.d
etc/network/if-post-down.d
etc/network/if-post-up.d
etc/network/if-pre-down.d
etc/network/if-pre-up.d
etc/network/if-up.d
etc/ssl/cert.pem
etc/ssl/ct_log_list.cnf
etc/ssl/ct_log_list.cnf.dist
etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.dist
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
etc../Playground/
```

Может есть у кого предложения для открытия всех файлов.
А также возможно есть более лучший способ вывода файлов.
glob не плох но наверное есть вореанты лучше!

Comment: а зачем выводить 8 гигабайт файлов? Кто их будет читать?

Comment: @Ипатьев нет времени объяснять, выводи все файлы!

Comment: а вас не смущает какое-то зацикливание в конце вывода?  `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` был какой-то для  обхода дерева